Understanding でも午前中商店街の線は濃厚になって来た気がする
In this panel, he can be seen planning things to do in a full-day long date:

I am not sure about this part:

でも午前中商店街の線は濃厚になって来た気がする

In particular, I am confused about the meaning of 線. It seems like it is used in sense of this definition:

❹ 物事を行う上での（漠然とした）方針や道筋。
「その━で考えてみよう」

It means something like 可能性?

You guessed the right definition in the dictionary. But it's not like "possibility" (可能性); I like these translations from jisho.org very much (specially approach for this context):

8. line (of action); position; approach; policy; principle​


Thanks, it seems like it is the duplicate of this question. I hope my question will be closed.
